# VideoToolbox can't decode MFT encoded H264 properly

Tags: ios, h.264, ms-media-foundation, video-toolbox

Did anyone experience an issue where VideoToolbox can't decode Media Foundation Transform (MFT) encoded H264 properly?  The decoded frame has green block distortion more than half of the frame.  I tried [Livy Stork's example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525000/how-to-use-videotoolbox-to-decompress-h-264-video-stream) for decoding MFT encoded H264, which is transmitted over network from PC video endpoint running on Windows 7 desktop.  I'm using Xcode 6.3 and running it on iOS 8 devices.

**Clue**: Same algorithm works fine when MFT encoded H264 comes from PC video endpoint running on Windows 8 or 8.1 desktop/tablet.  According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797816%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), most codec properties aren't supported in Windows 7, but I can't figure it out which property makes the difference...

Answer (score 1):

But if you **replace all the start code of all the NALUs, it should work**. I have successfully solved a problem that using Video Toolbox to decode a data array with multiple I slices or multiple p slice when they start with 4 bytes start code then following 8 slice with 3 bytes start code. Just replace every start code with slice length respectively. Note that slice length doesn't include start code length, you should ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out MFT H264 encoder on Windows 7 returns a frame with multiple NALs.  VideoToolbox decoder requires the NAL start code (0x00 00 00 01) to be replaced with the NAL size; when it finds the second NAL start code in the frame, it stops decoding.  Again MFT H264 encoder on Windows 8 or higher doesn't do this.