# AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer pixelated and laggy

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, h.264, video-toolbox

I'm attempting to use AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer coupled with ffmpeg to play a network stream on iOS. I've gotten the video to show up with help of [How to use VideoToolbox to decompress H.264 video stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525000/how-to-use-videotoolbox-to-decompress-h-264-video-stream/29525001#29525001).

However, when there's a lot of motion in the video stream I get a lot of lag, pixelation, and the picture looks very blocky. Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Does you get video data via TCP? and is't playing smooth but have some pixels ?