# How to hardcode a MP4 stream file with iOS VideoToolbox and FFMPEG?

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, hardcode, video-toolbox

Guys!

I have found a demo in github that is :[-VideoToolboxDemo](https://github.com/adison/-VideoToolboxDemo/blob/master/testFrameExtractor/testFrameExtractor/SuperVideoFrameExtractor.m). And I also found a question in stackoverflow [how-to-use-videotoolbox-to-decompress-h-264-video-stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525000/how-to-use-videotoolbox-to-decompress-h-264-video-stream) which someone has implemented in github:https:/ /github.com/lileilei1119/VTDemo

But there is a different between they in finding SPS and PPS.

The VideoToolboxDemo is:

```
uint8_t *data = pCodecCtx -> extradata;
int size = pCodecCtx -> extradata_size;
```

it uses extradata of pCodecCtx from FFMPEG to find start code like 0x00 00 01(or 0x00 00 00 01)

but the introduction in stackoverflow is:

```
[_h264Decoder decodeFrame:packet.data withSize:packet.size];
```

use data of packet?

I have try these two ways, but I still can't find start code of SPS and PPS. Does anyone know why? Is there something wrong in my file?

My mp4 file is http:/ /7u2m53.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/201601131107187320.mp4

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should print some of the file contents out to see if those codes exist. You'll need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) within the post, unless someone is already working with this library most people are not going to download both libraries and an unknown file to try to answer your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Videotoolbox does not use annex b, hence does not produce a start code. Read more here. [Possible Locations for Sequence/Picture Parameter Set(s) for H.264 Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884827/possible-locations-for-sequence-picture-parameter-sets-for-h-264-stream)