# How to convert NSData object to CMSampleBuffer

Tags: ios, streaming

I have two Apps now, one of those convert the CMSampleBuffer video data to NSData object, then transport it via network.Another App receive those data, now how can I convert NSData object back to CMSampleBuffer data?

Here is a way I use it to convert CMSampleBuffer to NSData object:

```
CMBlockBufferRef blockBufferRef = CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer(sampleBuffer);
size_t length = CMBlockBufferGetDataLength(blockBufferRef);
Byte buffer[length];

CMBlockBufferCopyDataBytes(blockBufferRef, 0, length, buffer);
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:length];
```

Or I just need another way to transport the video data?

Comment: Try to do it as here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29525001/7849097

Comment: Did you manage to convert nsdata back to samplebuffer?

Comment: Did you solve it by chance?

Comment: Any idea? got stuck at here.