# VideoToolbox on iOS 11 SDK works oddly

Tags: swift, h.264, compression, ios11.2

I developed H264 player (most ideas are taken from [How to use VideoToolbox to decompress H.264 video stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525000/how-to-use-videotoolbox-to-decompress-h-264-video-stream)) and it worked on XCode 8.2.1 perfectly.
But now I built the same project in XCode 9.2 and for iOS 11.2 SDK and it works in emulator but does not work on real device (iPad mini 2 with iOS 11.2.6) only partly - it decodes low bitrate videos(IDR slice size < 10 kB) but spits error -12909 and after 30-50 frames crashes on VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame()

Has anybody faced with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

After a week i found the cause of this issue. Looks like

CMBlockBufferCreateWithMemoryBlock works somethig different. When i manage memory block myself and call this method with

kCFAllocatorNull to avoid memory release, decoder fails. Even if i call decoding sicronously to guaranty that memory block valid during decoding.

So i added allocation and copy of memory block before  call CMBlockBufferCreateWithMemoryBlock and pass nil instead kCFAllocatorNull to use default deallocator when memory block should be released.