# IOS from NSData to NALUs and video buffers

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer, video-toolbox

I want to start working on a low level video player, at this stage, Iam able to download the videos from the server cache them, play them with AVPlayer.
what I want to do is to remove the AVPlayer, replace it with low level API's (AVFoundation, CoreMedia, VideoToolbox ...) 
Iam stuck at getting the NALUs from the NSData.
could anyone point me to something useful? .

Comment: Here is a very good introduction on how to extract the NALUs from NSData:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29525001
You have to find out in which format the NSData contains the NALUs. When the video is stored in a file, they are usually preceeded with 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01. When transmitted over RTP, there is no prefix(the size of the RTP packet payload is the size of the NALU) or the NALU is segmented(FU-A/FU-B Nalu types). If they are transmitted over RTP you can find more information about the structure here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6184

Comment: thank you, I'll check it out

Comment: Hi. Iam stuck at some point, can you help me go on ?

Comment: yes, edit your question

Comment: can we talk in mails , or in some chat app ? 
its so specific, and long explanation.

Comment: Nah, that's not the purpose of stackoverflow ;)