# Problem in decoding h264 raw frame in swift

Tags: swift, video, video-processing, h.264, video-toolbox

I try to decode an inputstream of [UInt8] to h264 video , I have search the whole web and read the beautiful detailed answer of olivia [How to use VideoToolbox to decompress H.264 video stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525000/how-to-use-videotoolbox-to-decompress-h-264-video-stream/29525001#29525001) , I tried to convert her objc answer to swift but it didn't worked for me .

Then i came to this nice pod https://github.com/songbihai/VideoDecoder?ref=iosexample.com the problem is i am getting some of images completely and some other in half green , [image: this the image i am getting]

Beside this image issue , the other issue i have is this code doesn't work on real device(iPad pro 2019 , iOS 15), and gives me

> DecodeError.decompressionOutputCallback(-12909)

which as I searched means bad data(!?) , and this is just for my stream the example file included in pod is ok, I tried to tweak some parameters but when I did it just didn't give me anything both on simulator and the real device.

this is one part of data that I'm getting

> 1, 0, 0, 0, 85, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 253, 8, 0, 0, 6, 102, 1, 0, 53, 3, 0, 0, 4, 1, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 97, 224, 112, 124, 79, 87, 150, 179, 234, 117, 62, 173, 161, 255, 77, 252, 87, 185, 125, 113, 31, 255, 255, 87, 241, 151, 222, 199, 142, 213, 117, 121, 250, 180, 99, 215, 101, 247, 175, 94, 229, 188, 214, 166, 189, 243, 107, 139, 188, 215, 170, 203, 138, 174, 181, 38, 226, 122, 180, 220, 187, 228, 229, 239, 8, 47, 215, 235, 245, 253, 98, 247, 23, 186, 235, 81, 26, 155, 189, 241, 21, 87, 142, 235, 95, 90, 159, 171, 212, 35, 147, 171, 244, 228, 234, 241, 61, 106, 78, 173, 84, 174, 242, 195, 61, 125, 117, 175, 171, 205, 85, 105, 175, 25, 213, 165, 234, 247, 214, 162, 124, 208, 133, 123, 95, 87, 174, 181, 17, 187, 235, 95, 87, 133, 191, 93, 111, 35, 249, 122, 212, 41, 214, 164, 235, 215, 205, 127, 212, 223, 191, 12, 49, 122, 123, 105, 188, 144, 238, 35, 171, 86, 253, 195, 143, 233, 252, 109, 215, 213, 170, 173, 234, 94, 181, 9, 119, 175, 142, 147, 179, 235, 213, 246, 229, 234, 213, 213, 190, 251, 201, 221, 120, 222, 175, 243, 111, 164, 55, 101, 191, 19, 17, 151, 155, 215, 94, 241, 253, 90, 47, 171, 117, 151, 81, 92, 215, 125, 87, 147, 63, 55, 180, 77, 221, 99, 43, 223, 175, 17, 141, 239, 79, 44, 51, 215, 213, 103, 228, 247, 87, 147, 173, 77, 201, 218, 147, 247, 136, 172, 188, 180, 250, 234, 213, 173, 105, 235, 123, 234, 213, 19, 87, 174, 181, 10, 94, 171, 93, 90, 42, 176, 142, 19, 221, 127, 47, 74, 185, 123, 207, 133, 101, 198, 233, 100, 132, 57, 111, 253, 94, 90, 196, 86, 126, 11, 123, 232, 246, 155, 147, 165, 9, 117, 120, 158, 189, 92, 102, 143, 189, 157, 143, 96, 95, 193, 85, 27, 119, 109, 46, 214, 131, 171, 227, 175, 233, 116, 116, 252, 22, 117, 183, 99, 243, 102, 190, 47, 58, 134, 47, 69, 241, 158, 187, 123, 116, 244, 31, 193, 12, 210, 216, 216, 141, 189, 245, 168, 67, 115, 241, 126, 158, 223, 198, 250, 91, 116, 52, 61, 122, 15, 151, 211, 252, 41, 236, 39, 76, 149, 239, 122, 119, 191, 205, 175, 224, 135, 216, 153, 240, 133, 47, 64, 126, 255, 31, 211, 219, 247, 246, 89, 24, 227, 55, 39, 87, 159, 113, 187, 142, 234, 208, 75, 184, 107, 130, 75, 125, 136, 156, 146, 110, 93, 250, 140, 234, 245, 120, 158, 93, 15, 124, 157, 168, 142, 181, 238, 28, 235, 221, 226, 123, 167, 196, 98, 100, 220, 70, 225, 77, 215, 86, 251, 239, 47, 55, 181, 226, 116, 251, 89, 186, 180, 61, 201, 111, 139, 230, 239, 92, 212, 184, 107, 171, 198, 106, 106, 205, 201, 127, 228, 239, 25, 213, 253, 43, 201, 201, 127, 230, 244, 15, 203, 75, 146, 209, 188, 184, 42, 241, 60, 154, 235, 151, 75, 124, 221, 185, 111, 55, 90, 159, 154, 203, 136, 172, 70, 235, 190, 178, 240, 81, 218, 191, 98, 184, 158, 221, 127, 190, 213, 242, 122, 248, 202, 210, 233, 94, 148, 170, 149, 14, 184, 78, 191, 183, 226, 180, 187, 31, 225, 46, 236, 73, 255, 25, 239, 163, 214, 235, 97, 176, 252, 37, 239, 189, 112, 81, 234, 170, 142, 223, 8, 251, 237, 167, 106, 190, 16, 238, 235, 178, 176, 255, 31, 207, 11, 59, 185, 55, 191, 130, 207, 44, 45, 232, 156, 198, 255, 17, 181, 75, 68, 161, 30, 79, 114, 113, 93, 236, 249, 121, 111, 205, 194, 22, 182, 244, 237, 255, 8, 119, 245, 98, 254, 46, 213, 83, 206, 24, 15, 197, 221, 191, 127, 132, 111, 125, 157, 200, 65, 219, 126, 59, 96, 94, 195, 158, 25, 249, 169, 255, 8, 123, 62, 205, 28, 141, 75, 193, 85, 135, 172, 112, 221, 213, 45, 34, 241, 222, 77, 161, 49, 253, 175, 139, 221, 171, 21, 143, 229, 218, 252, 20, 216, 246, 223, 175, 175, 138, 239, 162, 252, 18, 119, 215, 197, 123, 105, 115, 117, 233, 234, 111, 75, 223, 181, 228, 245, 39, 94, 139, 226, 55, 223, 251, 223, 241, 30, 233, 255, 116, 139, 15, 196, 211, 96, 189, 126, 74, 86, 171, 143, 223, 183, 250, 249, 50, 209, 159, 238, 203, 79, 242, 81, 214, 184, 139, 243, 193, 47, 196, 82, 73, 157, 36, 177, 60, 186, 89, 121, 54, 13, 63, 146, 151, 91, 147, 114, 110, 54, 241, 29, 106, 78, 246, 121, 47, 27, 29, 119, 230, 239, 210, 63, 37, 248, 138, 199, 245, 121, 55, 62, 235, 8, 43, 68, 110, 159, 10, 197, 117, 105, 249, 186, 197, 245, 98, 126, 172, 85, 97, 110, 111, 105, 64

Comment: About the "half images" might be the P and B frames of H264 codec. A full picture would be a keyframe. Then P/B frames only hold the changed pixels from keyframe. Try passing bytes of `last keyframe + your P/B frame` as one unit...